# Foreign Key Unexpected

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys, create-table

I'm using MySQL workbench and I am trying to create a table consist of foreign key using SQL Query. I am having problem with the Foreign part.

```
create table employee_position
(
ePID int primary key,
ePName varchar(45) not null,
eID int foreign key references employee_profile(eID)
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your syntax is wrong. Try:

```
create table employee_position
(
ePID int primary key,
ePName varchar(45) not null,
eID int,
foreign key (keyname) references employee_profile(eID)
)
```

For more information see the [mysql documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
create table employee_position
(
  ePID int primary key,
  ePName varchar(45) not null,
  eID int,
  foreign key (eID) references employee_profile(eID)
)
```

#### [SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ab184/1)

Answer (score 0):

Check [**FOREIGN KEYS**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html) in MySQL.

Try this:

```
CREATE TABLE employee_position
(
   ePID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   ePName VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
   eID INT NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (ePID),
   KEY CustomerID (eID),
   CONSTRAINT FK_employee_position_EP 
           FOREIGN KEY (eID) 
           REFERENCES employee_profile (eID) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
);
```

Comment: Jens has solved my problem but you really helped me with " on delete cascade on update cascade  " where i need this too.